# How do I Run a Script When Emails are Added to a Shared Folder?

Tags: vba, email, powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I am working with a group of people who are all using Outlook 2007 in combination with Exchange 2007.  Among us, we have shared folders on the network, and one of these folders will periodically receive emails that must be processed.  Is there a way to get Outlook to execute a script (VBA, PowerShell, what have you) whenever a new email is added to this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a shared folder on the network (smb) you can use the filesystemwatcher class from the system.io namespace.
If it's  mailfolder in a mailbox then you can use an outlook com object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Items.ItemAdd event will fire on the Items collection from that folder (MAPIFolder.Items). Make sure your keep Items variable in a global (class) variable to make sure its stays alive and hence able to raise events.